# Getting a cropped combination of 9 2D numpy arrays (only want boundaries of middle array)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 9 individual 2D numpy arrays that are each 3x3, I want to join at the edges like example:

`111222333
111222333
111222333
444555666
444555666
444555666
777888999
777888999
777888999`

Except I only want the nearby boundaries of any array that isn't the middle one, like example:

`12223
45556
45556
45556
78889`

[Here is the code I used to generate the first example.](http://pastebin.com/raw/QuKDfjCN) I have been considering using another function to crop the combined array (9x9 down to 5x5 in terms of the example) but I'm concerned about performance and I don't know how to achieve that either.

Comment: Could you copy paste the code instead of showing us the screenshot and also could you add the expected output in array format?

Answer (score 1):

Since you know you want to drop the first and last two columns of your 9x9 array, I would just use NumPy's indexing:

```
>>> x = np.arange(81).reshape((9,9))
>>> x
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26],
       [27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
       [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
       [45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53],
       [54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62],
       [63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71],
       [72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80]])
>>> x[:,2:-2]
array([[ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
       [29, 30, 31, 32, 33],
       [38, 39, 40, 41, 42],
       [47, 48, 49, 50, 51],
       [56, 57, 58, 59, 60],
       [65, 66, 67, 68, 69],
       [74, 75, 76, 77, 78]])
```

`x[:,2:-2]` means all rows (`:`), drop first two and last two columns (`2:-2`).